# JQuery binding issue with jquery generated accordion menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, bind, accordion

I an using a script to create an accordion menu and it works well with the menu in the html as can be seen in [test1](http://www.ab-mobile-apps.com/app/hapman/test1/index.html#build)

I am using the same accordian script in another directory that calls a jquery ajax call to retrieve the list info fron a database.  [test2](http://www.ab-mobile-apps.com/app/hapman/test2/index.html#build)

The issue is that in test2 the list populates but the accordion script does not open the menu.  It is as if the child lists are not even there.  When viewed from source the child list have an element of hidden in the code but the accordion never opens and displays visible.

For some reason the function is not binding to the menu that is generated from the jQuery script.

In test2 the script is call > body onload="loadData();".  Is is not called in test1.

The difference can be viewed at both links.

Any suggestions and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see some differences in your DOM structure: the working menu has some classes on the li elements (class="ui-link active" ), the broken one has not. Maybe that's the problem. See that you add the classes to the second example.